# Swift classes added after pods installed do not register modules

Tags: swift, firebase, import, cocoapods

I'm making in app that involves Firebase, and when I add Firebase to the project, all pre-existing classes work fine. However, after adding Firebase, whenever I create a new swift class (such as a new UIViewController class) and import any firebase modules in it:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase //Works in files created before pods installed... 
                //...but not files created after

class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The import statement throws "No such module Firebase". All classes that were added before still register the import though. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: That sounds like an Xcode error. Have you tried closing Xcode, cleaning your build, or just reinstalling the pod?

Comment: @DoesData Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried all three, however, and the error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Clean your derived data.
- Do a fresh `pod install`
- Do clean build and then do just build(cmd+b)
- Now add import statement in your class - `import Firebase` and then it should start working.